# Question about proof of Kolmogorov inequality for Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

The question is about one inequality which shows in Kolmogorov's paper ([inequality (3.1)](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81156038.pdf)) but is not proved. The inequality says that, if we assume $Y_1,Y_2,\ldots$ are i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables with expectation $p$, then the following inequality holds
$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{k\ge n} |\overline{Y}_k - p|\ge \varepsilon \right) \le 2 e^{-2 n \varepsilon^2 (1 - \varepsilon)} \qquad \text{for any $\varepsilon>0$,}$$
where $\overline{Y}_k = \sum_{j=1}^k Y_j / k = S_k / k$.
To prove and improve this inequality, several people made contributions. However, I found I got lost when reading several steps in the proofs of these literature.

1. [Paper 1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016771529400120W) discusses a general case where Bernoulli random variables are independent but not identical. However, in the 9th line of the proof of the Lemma 1 (key lemma), it seems that the inequality is contrary to the assumption ($\phi_i^\varepsilon (t) \ge 1$). Without Lemma 1, we cannot get the inequality we want.
2. [Paper 2](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0167715287900435) improves the inequality proposed by Kolmogorov. However, Lemma 1 is also weird. First it cites Lemma 3 in [paper 3](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1129050), but the definition of $\phi_\varepsilon (\lambda)$ (paper 2) and $\varphi_\varepsilon (\lambda)$ (paper 3) are different, with opposite sign before $\lambda$. Despite this fact, both these two lemmas are strange. They say that: let $\varepsilon\ge 0$, if there exists a $\lambda>0$ s.t. $\phi_\varepsilon (\lambda) = \mathbb{E} (e^{\lambda (X_i - \varepsilon)}) \le 1$, then
   $$ \mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{k\ge n} \frac{\sum_{i=1}^k Y_i}{k} \ge \varepsilon \right) \le \left[ \phi_\varepsilon(\lambda) \right]^n. $$
   It is strange that the inequality is also true (trivial) if $\phi_\varepsilon (\lambda) > 1$. We only needs to find that minimum of $\phi_\varepsilon(\lambda)$ when we fix an $\varepsilon$.
3. Then I checked the proof in [paper 3](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1129050), especially the proof of Lemma 2. I did not find mistakes except one citation in the first line of the proof. It is a [Russian book](https://books.google.com/books/about/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81.html?id=DQv_AgAAQBAJ) and we need theorem in page 183. In the proof, it defines a random variable $\eta (x) = \inf \{ i: 0\le i\le n, S_i \ge x \}$. However, I did not understand the following inequality.
   $$ \mathbb{E} (e^{t S_n} \mid \eta(x) = k) \ge e^{tx} \mathbb{E}(e^{t S_{n-k}}). $$
   I guess it uses the independence of $Y_i$, but I think here we need conditional independence, and it is not true since $\eta(x)$ is defined by $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$.

I truly wish you can give me some hints, no matter on whether this inequality is true, or on where I can find the correct proof, or on whether the ''mistakes'' I found is right. Thank you. Any comments help.

Comment: The inequality is proved in the book Probability by Shiryaev [Chapter I, §6, around eq. (42)].

Comment: I don't think so. The GTM book you mentioned only proves the case where there is no "sup". Thanks for your comment.

Comment: But once you know that $\mathbb{P}(|\bar{Y}_n - p|) \leq 2e^{-2n \epsilon^2}$, you simply sum over $n$: $\mathbb{P}(\sup_{k\geq n}|\bar{Y}_k - p|)\leq \sum_{k\geq n} \mathbb{P}(|\bar{Y}_k - p|)= \frac{2e^{-2n\epsilon^2}}{1-e^{-2\epsilon^2}}$. This is not exactly what you're looking for but maybe it helps.

Comment: Yes, we can have the exponential rate in this way, but not as beautiful as the one I want. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: @Greenhand In Kolmogorov's paper, "In another paper, we shall prove" (3.1). What's that paper?

Comment: According to my limited knowledge, he did not prove it. I hope it is my fault that I did not find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the inequality in your third part, here is my explanation: Conditional on $\eta(x)=k$, we have $S_k\geqslant x$ and $S_{k-1}<x$, and the conditional distribution of $Y_{k+1},\dots,Y_n$ is the same as the unconditional distribution of them. Hence

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E} (\mathrm{e}^{t S_n} \mid \eta(x) = k)&=\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{t(S_k+S_n-S_k)}\mid\eta(x)=k) \geqslant \mathrm e^{tx} \mathbb{E}(e^{t (S_{n}-S_k)}\mid\eta(x)=k)\\
&=\mathrm e^{tx}\mathbb E(e^{t(S_{n}-S_k)})=\mathrm e^{tx}\mathbb E(e^{tS_{n-k}})
.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found this point yesterday. Thanks again for your careful reading!